# People choosing numbers - uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

there's a group of 100 people. each one chose a number that distributes uniformly $Ud~(1,50)$.
$X$ is all the numbers that got chosen. What is the $E(x)$?

So all I got to do is $(1+50)/2$ and to multiply it by $100$? or is there a trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, there is no a trick but a very important reason for that

What you are asking to calculate is

$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}X_i]=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}\mathbb{E}[X_1]=\frac{1+50}{2}$$